# pandas reading the header only for the first column, returns "Unnamed" as the rest

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv file with about 82836 rows × 83 columns. The first column "Epoch" needs to be set as the index and declared as datetime format. When I try to load the csv file and set the first row as the header using `header=0` it only reads the header for the first column and returns "Unnamed" for the rest of the columns.

I am including a small snippet of the csv file.

```
Epoch                    1.12E+04    1.25E+04    1.41E+04    1.58E+04
               
2020-312T00:00:00.746   2.4660e-15  2.3305e-15  2.9498e-15  7.4974e-15
2020-312T00:00:01.746   1.4063e-14  1.3197e-14  6.5884e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:02.746   9.3894e-15  7.5422e-15  5.4330e-15  2.3551e-15
2020-312T00:00:03.746   5.2527e-15  4.3381e-15  6.5884e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:04.746   5.2527e-15  9.3456e-15  3.3400e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:05.746   6.9815e-15  9.3456e-15  1.1581e-14  6.3209e-15
2020-312T00:00:06.746   9.3894e-15  2.7787e-15  5.4330e-15  3.0432e-15
2020-312T00:00:07.746   8.1850e-15  5.6205e-15  2.5233e-15  2.6651e-15
2020-312T00:00:08.746   3.7247e-15  4.3381e-15  8.2865e-15  7.4974e-15
2020-312T00:00:09.746   5.2527e-15  1.3197e-14  8.2865e-15  6.3209e-15
2020-312T00:00:10.746   6.1547e-15  5.6205e-15  3.8158e-15  4.3281e-15
2020-312T00:00:11.746   6.9815e-15  7.5422e-15  4.3232e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:12.746   9.3894e-15  7.5422e-15  8.2865e-15  7.4974e-15
```

^ The csv file looks something like this.
I tried the following;

```
df = pd.read_csv('localfilepath/filename.csv', header=0)
df.set_index('Epoch', inplace = True)
df
```

And it returns something like this, with the index set to the Epoch column

```
Epoch                    1.12E+04    Unnamed:2    Unnamed:3  Unnamed:4
               
2020-312T00:00:00.746   2.4660e-15  2.3305e-15  2.9498e-15  7.4974e-15
2020-312T00:00:01.746   1.4063e-14  1.3197e-14  6.5884e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:02.746   9.3894e-15  7.5422e-15  5.4330e-15  2.3551e-15
2020-312T00:00:03.746   5.2527e-15  4.3381e-15  6.5884e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:04.746   5.2527e-15  9.3456e-15  3.3400e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:05.746   6.9815e-15  9.3456e-15  1.1581e-14  6.3209e-15
2020-312T00:00:06.746   9.3894e-15  2.7787e-15  5.4330e-15  3.0432e-15
2020-312T00:00:07.746   8.1850e-15  5.6205e-15  2.5233e-15  2.6651e-15
2020-312T00:00:08.746   3.7247e-15  4.3381e-15  8.2865e-15  7.4974e-15
2020-312T00:00:09.746   5.2527e-15  1.3197e-14  8.2865e-15  6.3209e-15
2020-312T00:00:10.746   6.1547e-15  5.6205e-15  3.8158e-15  4.3281e-15
2020-312T00:00:11.746   6.9815e-15  7.5422e-15  4.3232e-15  5.2453e-15
2020-312T00:00:12.746   9.3894e-15  7.5422e-15  8.2865e-15  7.4974e-15
```

What can I do to fix this issue and set the Epoch column as datetimeindex?

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Please provide the content of the CSV file in its exact format, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @mozway Hi, I copy pasted it exactly from the csv file. Is there a way to include a csv file? The original file is over 70MB

Comment: Try: `pd.read_csv(filename, sep=r'\s+', header=0, index_col=0)`

Comment: Are you sure this is a csv file? It looks moire like a tsv file to me. I do not see any commas separating table cells but tabs (or spaces).

Comment: @mozway I tried that and it didnt work, it returned something very strange where every data point got turned into a header

Comment: @Sandwichnick Hi, I copy pasted it from a csv file. I'm not sure how to include a csv file here

Comment: @new-to-coding that's the issue, maybe non-standard characters that mess up your import. Any way you could share the original file (eventually truncated to its first few lines **if the truncated file also reproduces your issue**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using pandas 1.3.5.

I have copied the example you gave into a file example.tsv.

This line works for me:

```
df = pd.read_table("data/example.tsv", sep='\s+').set_index('Epoch')
df
```

This outputs the DataFrame:

```
                            1.12E+04        1.25E+04    1.41E+04         1.58E+04
Epoch               
2020-312T00:00:00.746   2.466000e-15    2.330500e-15    2.949800e-15    7.497400e-15
2020-312T00:00:01.746   1.406300e-14    1.319700e-14    6.588400e-15    5.245300e-15
2020-312T00:00:02.746   9.389400e-15    7.542200e-15    5.433000e-15    2.355100e-15
2020-312T00:00:03.746   5.252700e-15    4.338100e-15    6.588400e-15    5.245300e-15
2020-312T00:00:04.746   5.252700e-15    9.345600e-15    3.340000e-15    5.245300e-15
2020-312T00:00:05.746   6.981500e-15    9.345600e-15    1.158100e-14    6.320900e-15
2020-312T00:00:06.746   9.389400e-15    2.778700e-15    5.433000e-15    3.043200e-15
2020-312T00:00:07.746   8.185000e-15    5.620500e-15    2.523300e-15    2.665100e-15
2020-312T00:00:08.746   3.724700e-15    4.338100e-15    8.286500e-15    7.497400e-15
2020-312T00:00:09.746   5.252700e-15    1.319700e-14    8.286500e-15    6.320900e-15
2020-312T00:00:10.746   6.154700e-15    5.620500e-15    3.815800e-15    4.328100e-15
2020-312T00:00:11.746   6.981500e-15    7.542200e-15    4.323200e-15    5.245300e-15
2020-312T00:00:12.746   9.389400e-15    7.542200e-15    8.286500e-15    7.497400e-15
```